# How can I order an array not alphabetical PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want order an array but not alphabetically, I have this:

```
Array(
'D' => 40
'S' => 60
'C' => 50
'I' => 60
)
```

And it must be order by descending value:

```
Array(
 'S' => 60
 'I' => 60
 'C' => 50
 'D' => 40
)
```

but if there are repeat values, then the order must be like `D > I > S > C`:

```
Array(
 'I' => 60
 'S' => 60
 'C' => 50
 'D' => 40
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `but if there are repeat values , then the order must be like D > I > S > C:` not clear

Comment: @user007 the alphabet indicates C is before S, but in my case the letters must follow this order.. (first) D - I - S - C (last)

Comment: Are there only 4 keys in this array always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array(    
    'C'=>60, 
    'S'=>10,
    'I'=>20,
    'D'=>60
);

arsort($array); //sorts in descending order

$unique = array_unique($array,SORT_REGULAR); //get unique values - returns 60,20,10

$finalarray = array();
$order = array('D','I','S','C'); //defining the sort order priority
foreach($unique as $val){

    $key =  array_keys($array, $val); //get all keys that have the similar value (for duplicates)
        foreach($order as $val2){
            if(in_array($val2,$key)){ //check key according to order of priority keys
                $finalarray[$val2] = $array[$val2];
            }

        }

}

var_dump($finalarray);
```

[Fiddle here.](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/m76-4u2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) function

It sorts array maintaining index association.

```
$arr = array('I' => 60, 'S' => 60, 'C' => 50, 'D' => 40);
asort($arr);
```

But you shouldn't expect a certain sorting order for equal values, because if any of sort functions evaluates two members as equal then the order is undefined (the sorting is not stable).

You can implement sorting both by value and key through creation of 2 auxillary arrays for keys and values and then using `array_multisort` function:

```
$arr = array(
    'I' => 60,
    'S' => 60,
    'C' => 50,
    'D' => 40
);

$tag = array();
$num = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $tag[] = $key;
    $num[] = $value;
}

array_multisort($num, SORT_DESC, $tag, SORT_ASC, $arr);

var_dump($arr);

/* result of var_dump($arr):
array (size=4)
  'I' => int 60
  'S' => int 60
  'C' => int 50
  'D' => int 40
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the big problem is when two or more members are equals, i must do it in this way: D > I > S > C -.-

Comment: Thank you zavg, this solution solved the example that I proposed it, because the letters repeated can be sorted alphabetically but if the array is: D=>40, I=>50, S=>60, C=>60 not works...please help me :(

Comment: @user3252775 it works pretty well for me for both arrays... here is fiddle http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/ty7-q7m

Comment: The result must be array('S'=>60,'C'=>60,'I'=>50,'D'=>40) and not array('C'=>60,'S'=>60,'I'=>50,'D'=>40) because the question is that the rule must follow D > I > S > C. Sorry if I have not explained well. Thank you for everything!! ;)

Comment: @Lumilo just change `array_multisort($num, SORT_DESC, $tag, SORT_ASC, $arr);`  to `array_multisort($num, SORT_DESC, $tag, SORT_DESC, $arr);` for that case

Comment: @Lumilo  http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/qdq-r8b

Comment: Sorry @zavg for the delay, but the solution must be dynamic...if the value of 'D' is 10 or 60, and the value of 'S' is 20 or 30, for example, la solution must follow the explication that I pushed here. You are proposing a solution that for some cases it works but others not.. :S

Comment: @Lumilo Have you seen the second variant? phpfiddle.org/main/code/qdq-r8b

Comment: yes, i saw it but i was looking for a solution like the one proposed by user007.. in your code on second variant, if you change the values to: 'D'=>40, 'I'=>60,'S'=>60,'C'=>50, the result show 'S' before 'I' and the rule is that D-I-S-C ('I' before 'S'). Thanks for your help, sorry if you don't understand me when i explained the problem :S